# python printing the path names of .c files from a directory tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree, directory

I'm a beginner in Python.
I am trying to work with a directory tree that contains test cases (. files) at variable depth, say, test (top directory) has 2 children test1 and test 2. test1 has further branches t1 and t2 which contain t1.c and t2.c respectively. Similary, test2 has 2 children test21 and test22. test 21 has t3 and t4 which contain t3.c and t4.c resply. test22 has t5 and t6 which have t5.c and t6.c.
I am trying to search for the .c file and then print its path using recursion.

The error that I am getting is that the code tracerses through only one branch and does not go back to the previous level to go through the other branches. Please help me here.

Following is my code:

```
# assume, at no level folders and .c files are present at the same time

import os import fnmatch


# move to test directory 
os.chdir('/home/gyadav/test') 


# function to create a list of sub directories 
def create_subdir_list():
     subdirs = os.listdir('.')
     len_subdirs = len(subdirs) - 1
     # while i != length
     for i in range(0, len_subdirs):
         # move to next folder
         os.chdir(subdirs[i])
         print os.getcwd()
         subdirs1 = (os.listdir('.'))
         print subdirs1
         # call function - open thedirectory and check for .c file
         open_dir('.')


 # definition of check for . c file 
 def check_for_c():
     cfile = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('.'), '*.c')
     # if file found
     if len(cfile) != 0:
         # save the path
         path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(cfile[0]))
         print path
         os.chdir('..')
         print os.getcwd()

     else:
         create_subdir_list()


 def open_dir(name):
     check_for_c() 
     open_dir('.')
```

Comment: Please remove all the `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use your own way to practice python. But the efficient way would be :

```
>>> PATH = '/home/sijan/Desktop/'
>>> import os
>>> from glob import glob
>>> result = [y for x in os.walk(PATH) for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.py'))]
```

It will list all the .py files in the folder within the give path.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a more efficient way. I got the desired result very easily with your answer.
Though, could you suggest what the error could be in the recursion method? I can't seem to figure it out.